# Apply different textures to faces of an object

Tags: texturing, materials, faces

I find a lot of information about applying textures to objects, but when I try to look up info about applying different textures to each face of an object, it seems there's always a critical step left out.  For example, if I apply brick to one face of a wall, how do I get wallpaper on the opposite face?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.htmlhttps://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html

Comment: That's the same as with materials but depends on engine. If Cycles, edit material in Node edtitor and there add an Image texture node with desired texture for both materials. Though if you mean you want to make double-sided material (different materials on the sides of the same face) then it's a bit more complicated and involves setting up Geometry node with Backfacing used as factor

Comment: thank you Haunt, and thank you for those who marked it duplicate...I was sure that it was, but I'm just learning my way around sites like this.  The solution to my problem was simple: Limit selection to visible.  Problem Solved.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Select the faces you want to add the texture to, then go to the material editor and add an new slot by pressing the +, next hit assign. Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Hanna... Laughing at myself... it helps to turn on Limit selection to visible.